# E/RecyclerView No addapter attached, skipping layout

Tags: android

I am showing the list of reviews. I able to fetch the list from the server. But it is not display in the RecyclerView. In logcat it shows following:

```
03-14 14:34:32.360    6545-6545/com.couragedigital.petapp E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
03-14 14:34:32.391    6545-6545/com.couragedigital.petapp E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
03-14 14:34:32.425    6545-6545/com.couragedigital.petapp E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
03-14 14:34:32.433    6545-6545/com.couragedigital.petapp E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
03-14 14:35:00.626    6545-6545/com.couragedigital.petapp E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

**My Recyclerview**

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.clinicRateNReview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    reviewAdapter = new ClinicReviewsListAdapter(clinicReviewsListItemsArrayList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(reviewAdapter);
```

After that I am fetching list from server and added it to list and the notifying the adapter using `reviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Below is my Clinic Review Adapter code

```
public class ClinicReviewsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClinicReviewsListAdapter.ViewHolder>{

List<ClinicReviewsListItems> clinicReviewsListsItem;
View v;
ViewHolder viewHolder;

public ClinicReviewsListAdapter(List<ClinicReviewsListItems> clinicReviewsListArrayList) {
    this.clinicReviewsListsItem = clinicReviewsListArrayList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.clinic_review_list_items, viewGroup, false);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    ClinicReviewsListItems clinicReviewsListItems = clinicReviewsListsItem.get(i);
    viewHolder.bindClinicReviewsList(clinicReviewsListItems);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return clinicReviewsListsItem.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView clinicReviews;
    public TextView email;
    public View clinicListDividerLine;
    public int userRatings;
    LinearLayout layout;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        layout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingNos);
        clinicReviews = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.reviews);
        email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.usersName);
        clinicListDividerLine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewdividerline);
    }

    public void bindClinicReviewsList(ClinicReviewsListItems clinicReviewsList) {
        userRatings=Integer.parseInt(clinicReviewsList.getClinicRatings());

        for(int i=0;i<userRatings;i++)
        {
            ImageView image = new ImageView(v.getContext());
            image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(80,60));
            image.setMaxHeight(20);
            image.setMaxWidth(20);
            image.setId(i);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ratingstar_yellow);
            // Adds the view to the layout
            image.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
            layout.addView(image);
        }
        clinicReviews.setText(clinicReviewsList.getClinicReviews());
        email.setText(clinicReviewsList.getEmail());
        clinicListDividerLine.setBackgroundResource(R.color.list_internal_divider);
    }
}

}
```

**clinic recyclerview xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/clinicRateNReview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

**recyclerview list item xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/reviewLayout"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reviews"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/reviews"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rating:"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/ratingLabel"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/reviews"/>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="112dp"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ratingLabel"
                    android:id="@+id/ratingNos"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="By:"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/userNameLabel"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ratingNos"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/usersName"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/userNameLabel"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ratingNos"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
<View
        android:id="@+id/viewdividerline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/drawer_header_text"
        android:layout_below="@id/reviewLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show the part where you setup recyclerview

Comment: you have not attached the adapter to reyclerview

Comment: see my answer for more infio

Comment: post your xml of this fragment or activity

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
  recyclerView.setAdapter(reviewAdapter);
```

before notifydatasetchanged or after adapter creation.

Comment: try using height = "natch_parent"